# How to make multiple where queries while foreach

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I want to make more than one where on a query with Eloquent.
Basically you have this :

```
<?php

    User::where('gender', '=', 'male')->where('age', '=', '18')->get();

?>
```

So imagine you have a foreach which turns twice to concatenate that two where clause.
How could you do ?

```
$user = User::where('gender', '=', 'male')
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $user .= $user->where($key, '=', $value);
}
```

Do you see what I mean ? I know that my example is not possible at all.. but it's to explain.

Thank you !

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: I edit my post maybe its gonna be clearer

Comment: Still don't understand. Give some real example, because it's hard to guess what you mean by concatenating the object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following.

```
$user = User::where('gender', 'male');

// Now add on a chain with loops or whatever expression you need.
$user = $user->where('field', 'value');

// Now get the results
$user = $user->get();
```